# Why is Instagram's Swarm check-in so awful?

Tags: instagram, foursquare, integration

Since I've started using Instagram as a mean to post pictures and places in three networks at once (Instagram itself, Facebook and Swarm) I've noticed how badly Instagram links places to Swarm. It's *very, very common* to get checked in the city or neighborhood when I'm posting a picture in a restaurant, or even to be checked in to another generic place quite far from where I am.

How does Instagram link the places from its place search to Swarm venues?

Are there any tips on how to improve this to avoid bad check-ins?

I've tried to guess what places from the list would be the "correct" Swarm venue but never had luck with that.

Comment: Instagram uses facebook places whose data is awful.

Comment: @Sathya that could become an actual answer :)

Comment: tried to frame it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heard you, I used to rely on Instagram for the same workflow - publish to Facebook, Twitter, Swarm and Tumblr. Sometime soon after Facebook's acquisition of Instagram, they ditched FourSquare's location data in favour of [Facebook places](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2455555,00.asp) which is ridiculously bad in comparison to Foursquare, hence your bad check-ins.

There really aren't any tips, just hope that Facebook place has that location covered for you. There have been times where I selected a location in Instagram and the corresponding check-in has been a bland 'My Country' location which is pretty bad. Just do the check-in from Swarm manually

Comment: worst behaviour ever: checking in your country lol